# out of memory at line 1 Error in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm using PhotoChooserTask in order to select a photo from Gallery. When I click on a button to show PhotoChoosertask gallery opened. Now I came back without choosing any photo from gallery. here my app crashes. Is there any solution for this problem? Please Suggest.

```
void photochooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
    if (e.Error == null && e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
        bi.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        Myimage.Source = bi;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to open an Image.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks clean, and this will not give an OutOfMemory Exception. Can you make sure in which line of code, it breaks ?

Comment: Maybe the image you're trying to load is too big for the app's memory to handle. What's the exception log ? And at what line did it break?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
        {
            if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
            {
                System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
                bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);

                myImage.Source = bmp;
            }
        }
```